# Usage "For smth. to be " in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Would the following sentence be grammatically correct: "For practical co-operation it is essential to have a uniform interpretation of the used terms and definitions."
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would change the order slightly to say "... of the terms and definitions used". Otherwise, it is fine.